# weekly time series forecasting with exogenous variables retrain cadence

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a weekly forecasting model, which has exogenous variables. The forecasting horizon is 8 weeks ahead - 8 data points. I do forecast (8 weeks) the exogenous variables to use them as input for forecasting the target variables.

Due to complexity, the team suggested to just train the model once a month, which makes the prediction horizon to be 8, 9, 10, 11 weeks ahead for every week.

What is the best practice to retrain the time series model in such scenario? To train the model every week with the new added data, or without considering the new data?